# Difference between article meta description and Google result's presented text

Tags: articles, seo

I'm using Joomla 3.9 for posting my articles. I've recently noticed the meta description appearing for my articles on Google and the ones I've written in Joomla are different. It seems Google is just taking a snippet from the first paragraph of my article.

**This is seriously hurting my SEO. What can I do fix this?**

Comment: Do you have meta descriptions in both the menu item and the article?

Comment: I doubt very much that it is seriously hurting your SEO, in fact it's probably helping.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the page source of your site are the meta tags showing correctly?  Assuming that they are, then my answer is as follows.

Google will often provide its own metadescriptions, often different ones depending on the search and the searcher.  It will use the one you provide if it is unique enough and relevant enough and is suitable for the search context.  You cannot force Google to use the one you provide.

Metadescriptions do not directly effect seo, only click through rates which are effected  when the searcher reads the description in the result and like what they read.